# Why does my manifest.json file is having trouble compiling?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "somerandomname",
    "version": "2.0",
    "homepage_url": "https://url.com",
    "author": "somedude",
    "description": "extension"
},
"icons": {
    "48": "img/icon.svg",
    "96": "img/icon.svg"
},
```

The error in jsonlint is,

```
Error: Parse error on line 8:
...tion": "extension"},"icons": {   "48": 
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"icons"` field should be a part of the main object, not a separated entity:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "somerandomname",
    "version": "2.0",
    "homepage_url": "https://url.com",
    "author": "somedude",
    "description": "extension",
    "icons": {
        "48": "img/icon.svg",
        "96": "img/icon.svg"
    }
}
```